# Velocity IncludeEventHandler dilemma

Tags: spring, velocity

Here is an interesting problem regarding the IncludeEventHandler.

I am developing a Spring-Based application which uses velocity which has different *VENDORS* having a separate portfolio site. I am letting vendors customize the pages by providing them the Velocity templates which are being stored the database and are picked up by the velocity engine using a DataSourceResourceLoader.

My table is organized like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkFiQ.png).

The vendors may parse other templates by calling the macro `#parse` and passing their `vendorid/template-name` so that it looks like this.

```
#parse("20160109144/common-css.vm")
```

Now the actual problem is picking up the template according to vendorid.
I have a class (extending `IncludeEventHandler`) which overrides the `includeEvent` method. Now what can I do to return the desired template? I dont want to change the names and make them look like `20160109144/home.vm`

Comment: Jay - out of curiosity, the actual templates are referenced using {vendorid}/{template-name}.vm always right? If that's the case, can you split the name? You may have to override the DataSourceResourceLoader to munge that name instead of dealing with it at the IncludeEvent level.

Comment: Yes they always are referred as {vendorid}/{template-name}.vm. But actually I don't have idea how DataSourceResourceLoader EXACTLY works. I would appreciate if you could explain me mate. Cheers. D

Comment: I'm travelling this morning but I'll be glad to look into it and get back to you

Comment: Help appreciated... :)

Comment: I got side tracked this weekend and was unable to look at this - I'll see if I can get to it this in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OP's question, the intent was to provide an alternate behavior to the [DataSourceResourceLoader](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/velocity/engine/tags/1.7/src/java/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/DataSourceResourceLoader.java?view=markup).

Unfortunately, the Velocity Engine version 1.7 doesn't have ability to change the SQL statement that is used to retrieve the template.

The DataSourceResourceLoader extends the [ResourceLoader](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/velocity/engine/tags/1.7/src/java/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ResourceLoader.java?view=markup) abstract class. That said, if you [reference the source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/velocity/engine/tags/1.7/src/java/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/DataSourceResourceLoader.java?view=markup), you should be able to implement a custom ResourceLoader that behaves the way you want it to.

One option, glom most of the code from DataSourceResourceLoader and change the way it determines the template content to load from the database.

I would dump all of the query related material as you will be determining the specific columns you want to load for content. The DataSourceResourceLoader essentially maps the name of a template to a database entry and your implementation essentially revolves around the rules you've defined above.

Hopefully that can provide enough assistance to move forward. I would recommend pulling this in a debugger as well and determine what is and is-not passed in to the related load methods.

Comment: That solved my problem pretty much. I would accept your answer as soon as I get it working... Thanks for sending me in a proper way...

Comment: Very cool - I think the first usage of this loader was in the http://rollerweblogger.org/project/ somewhere back in like v2 - I was stunned that it was even possible but that was something like 14-15 years ago (can you believe it has been around that long?!)

Comment: No absolutely not. By the way, I spent my day configuring my new class. Works really perfectly. Thanks for the solution mate. Can you help me with file upload too?

Comment: I can, post another question and will look into it

Comment: Can I private message / mail you?

Comment: I think there is a chat feature on stack over flow we can use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100382/discussion-between-dave-g-and-jay).