# Configuring the DataSourceResourceLoader

Tags: java, velocity

In reference to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693988/velocity-includeeventhandler-dilemma), I want to know how can I configure the `DatasourceResourceLoader` to meet my requirements.

Being more specific, I am calling the `#parse()` macro like this.

```
#parse("$vendorid/template-name.vm")
```

And my table from which the templates are picked is organized like [image: this].

How do I interpret the `#parse()` macro to pick only the template which is put against the particular vendorid.

## Please Note These Points:

1. I don't want to change the table structure or the values of `name` column.
2. The `name` column may contain the redundant values, but the combination on `vendorid` and `name` would be never be the same.

**EDIT**

I am aware of the Velocity's `IncludeEventHandler`, if I can solve my problem by overriding this event, how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity's `IncludeEventHandler` won't solve your problem, as it can only change the path of the resource, not fetch the resource itself.

What you can, although, is create a view on the database side that will let you fetch the templates exactly how you want:

```
CREATE VIEW templates_view (id VARCHAR(100), html CLOB, ts DATETIME)
AS SELECT CONCAT(vendorid, '/', name) FROM templates;
```

That's the MySQL syntax, for other engines you'll use the TIMESTAMP type and/or the || concatenation operator, as needed...

This way you have a single key column to reach your templates and can initialize the DatasourceResourceLoader to use this view.

Comment: Thanks for hinting me. I solved the problem by referring to the other guy's answer and implementing what you are telling me. Both of you guys deserve appreciation. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693988/velocity-includeeventhandler-dilemma/34712886#34712886) reply, extending a class with `ResouceLoader` and using it as a `DataSourceResourceLoader` works seamlessly.